# Глобальный указатель вовсе не глобальный

Tags: c++, c

Имеются файлы:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3/sqlite3.h"
#include "global.h"
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    sqlite3_open16(L"blockchain2.db", &db_handler);

    __sqlite3_print__
    test();
    system("pause");
    sqlite3_close(db_handler);
    return 1;
}
```

`global.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "sqlite3/sqlite3.h"

#define sqlite3_reset(stmt) sqlite3_reset(stmt), sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
static sqlite3* db_handler;
#define __sqlite3_print__ cout << db_handler << endl;
```

`test.h`:

```
#pragma once

void test();

#include <iostream>
#include "global.h"

using namespace std;

void test() {
    __sqlite3_print__   
}
```

[image: Что не так с этим гадом?]

Что не так с этим гадом? Почему указатель из `test.cpp` пуст?

---

> такой результат невозможно получить с одной-единственной единицей трансляции. А у вас в вопросе она только одна - main.cpp. Единиц трансляции у вас на самом деле как минимум две.

Не совсем понял, о каких единицах трансляций говорится, если Вы про вывод на экран то в test.cpp есть вызов макроса.

Я пробовал `extern`, но получается тоже самое. Еще раз весь код:

```
// --------- main.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3/sqlite3.h"
#include "global.h"
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    sqlite3* db_handler;
    sqlite3_open16(L"sqlite3.db", &db_handler);

    __sqlite3_print__
    test();
    system("pause");
    sqlite3_close(db_handler);
    return 1;
}



// --------- global.h:

#pragma once
#include "sqlite3/sqlite3.h"

#define sqlite3_reset(stmt) sqlite3_reset(stmt), sqlite3_finalize(stmt)

extern sqlite3* db_handler;
#define __sqlite3_print__ cout << db_handler << endl;



// --------- test.h:

#pragma once

void test();



// --------- test.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "global.h"
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

sqlite3* db_handler;

void test() {

    __sqlite3_print__   
}
```

Comment: Что-то вы нас обманываете. Такой результат невозможно получить с одним единственным `.cpp` файлом.

Comment: Две версии кода принципиально отличаются.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, вы нас скорее всего обманываете: такой результат невозможно получить с одной-единственной единицей трансляции. А у вас в вопросе она только одна - `main.cpp`. Единиц трансляции у вас на самом деле как минимум две.

Во-вторых, и где ж тут глобальный указатель? `static` переменная - это статическая переменная, а не глобальная переменная. Этим `static` вы сами "убили" глобальность, т.е. попросили компилятор завести *отдельную* переменную для каждой единицы трансляции.

В С++17 у вас есть простой способ создавать глобальные переменные через заголовочный файл

```
inline sqlite3* db_handler;
```

А в более ранних версиях стандарта С++ и в С придется делать все классическим способом. В заголовочном файле объявляем

```
extern sqlite3* db_handler;
```

а в одном из файлов реализации определяем

```
sqlite3* db_handler;
```